# Adding object of class to Relative Layout in Android

Tags: java, android, class, view, android-relativelayout

I'm creating an object from a class that I have created and I want to add it to the relative view in a specific place
The problem that when I try to call one of the class functions by this object the program crashes

Here is my code in MainActivity

```
    MyClass obj1;
    obj1 = (MyClass)findViewById(R.id.MyClass_id);
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    obj1.init(this);
}
```

The program stops working as soon it reaches `obj1.init(this);`

Here is my xml code

```
       <com.Appl.Android.Widgets.MyClass
        android:id="@+id/MyClass_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/View01"/>
```

Comment: And what does the LogCat say? You need to learn to debug your own errors, it's not rocket science.

Comment: IIRC it is either mandatory or considered to be a good style to start resource IDs with lowercase.

Comment: At second, do your package names (`com.Appl.Android.Widgets.MyClass`) really start from uppercase letters?

Comment: move the initialization to `onCreate`.

Comment: @Kayaman I did try to understand what happening, I searched the message and I could not find anything that worked for me. I'm not just a lazy person that comes and ask without trying !!!!

Comment: @Raghunandan that did not work but I think the error is in this line `obj1 = (MyClass)findViewById(R.id.MyClass_id);` because it is not recognizing that it is an object from MyClass

Comment: @Lily well maybe not lazy. But you come here with a piece of code, won't show what the error message is, and expect us to help you? Come on. If you want help, make it easy to help you. Don't withhold information. Next time you ask a question, make sure you've read all the error messages, the LogCat output and **then** ask the question, and include those in it.